# how do disable force_ssl option for just one action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

in production environment.

I want to disable this setting just for one action.  (basically for one link)

How can i ?   I know i can globally turn it off but that will be the last choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem [rack-ssl-enforcer](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-ssl-enforcer) and set this configuration line in the production configuration file :

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, except: '/webservice'
```

You can replace /webservice by the link you want to disable SSL

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression with rack-ssl-enforcer to exclude a single action.

```html
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => ['/foo', %r{/bar$}]
```

This will exclude www.example.com/foo and www.example.com/items/1/bar. This can be helpful if you want to exclude just the 'bar' action for the items controller but not other actions.